# Eclipse neon not supporting on window7

Tags: ant, eclipse-neon

Recently I downloaded my Eclipse neon and updated today. Now I am facing lot of problem.1. Ant not supporting and not running or executing the code.2.Palette I was wondering to install some plugin it disappear from the IDE. I am not able to trace it. Now Property is not showing.When i downloaded the neon it was working fantastically but wen i updated it is not working anymore so kindly help me out with this. One more query IS I want to install eclipse neon for php,java,c,c++.How can I download in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty strange you got an update because there was no update of Neon since release...  Are you sure you didn't update Mars to Neon (which is not supported)?

To show properties: Window > Show View (or Alt+Shift+q q shortcut) > Properties.

To install Java, php et al: Help > Eclipse Marketplace, search for Java, then PHP then C++ and install them.